# Passing multiple files with asterisk to python shell in Windows

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I'm going through Google's Python exercises and I need to be able to do this from the command line:

```
python babynames.py --summaryfile baby*.html
```

Where `python` is the Python shell, `babynames.py` is the Python program, `--summaryfile` is an argument to be interpreted by my `babynames` program, and `baby*.html` is the list of files matching that expression.  However, it doesn't work and I'm not sure if the problem is the Windows command shell or Python.  The `baby*.html` expression is not being expanded out to the full list of files, instead it's being passed strictly as a string.  Can multiple files be passed to a Python program in such a way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Windows' command interpreter does not expand wildcards as UNIX shells do before passing them to the executed program or script.

```
python.exe -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]" *.txt
```

Result:

```
['*.txt']
```

Solution: Use the `glob` module.

```
from glob import glob
from sys import argv

for filename in glob(argv[1]):
    print filename
```

Comment: Do I need to check for the arguments containing wildcards and then use glob on those?...Or can I just use glob on all arguments?

Comment: Okay, it looks like I can just call glob on the file arguments whether they contain wildcards or not.  Glob-rific :)

Comment: Yes, a filename without any wildcards in it is a pattern that matches exactly one file (or none). The difference is you get an empty list from `glob()` in that case, rather than finding out later that the file does not exist. This is subtle but may change how you wish to handle errors.

Comment: I didn't get an empty list at all when I used a single filename without any wildcards.  It worked fine.

Comment: I meant to say, if the user specifies a non-wildcard filename and that file *does not exist,* you get an empty list, same as if the user didn't specify any files at all. The user may be surprised to get a "no matching files" message in this case rather than "file not found". As I said, subtle...

Comment: I want this in argparse. How to?

Comment: `argparse` isn't going to expand your wildcards for you, if that's what you're asking. You get the files the usual argparsey way and then expand them using `glob`.

Comment: Of course, this mean that, *technically*, you might experience different behaviour in a "cross-platform" script, e.g. if the user ran `python script.py --arg *.foo` or `python script.py --arg '*.foo'`.  Is the `glob` module cognizant of the shell from which you run the script (and its expansion rules)?

Answer (score 6):

Cross-platform:

```
import glob
if '*' in sys.argv[-1]:
     sys.argv[-1:] = glob.glob(sys.argv[-1])
continue...
```

Comment: Could also be a '?'

Comment: Actually the argument may be passed to `glob` without checking for asterisk, as path without wildcard is a valid `glob` argument. Then you don't need checking all options but at a cost of `glob` call (which presumably does the same anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using argparse:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(dest='wildcard',nargs='+')

print(parser.parse_args().wildcard)
```

Comment: Hmm.. I put this code in a `test.py` file, and called it from Anaconda cmd prompt with `python test.py *.json` (and there were `.json` files in same directory), and I got `['*.json']`, which means the wildcard was **not** expanded to actual filenames. So, this doesn't really work as answer to stated question.

Comment: Right on. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426881/1672826) explanation and link for Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from UNIX-like shells, right in the from you wrote. In my case, Git Bash did the job - it accepts asterisks as input and process them correctly.