# How to pass wildcard argument like *.txt in windows cmd

Tags: python, windows

My directory tree:

```
test/
|_____ 1.txt   content: 1_line1\n1_line2
|_____ 2.txt   content: 2_line1\n2_line2
|_____ test_fileinput.py
```

My Python script:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1:]):
     print(fileinput.filename(), fileinput.filelineno(), line)
```

First I tried it on Linux, as you see it works flawlessly:

```
$ python3 test_fileinput.py *.txt
1.txt 1 1_line1

1.txt 2 1_line2
2.txt 1 2_line1

2.txt 2 2_line2
```

But on Windows:

[image]

Of course I can do `python test_fileinput.py 1.txt 2.txt`, but I'm wondering is there a way that I could still pass **`*.txt`** on Windows? Thank you.

Comment: one option is to use *nix-like tools for windows, e.g. `cygwin`

Comment: @shx2 Surely cygwin works, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501761/passing-multple-files-with-asterisk-to-python-shell-in-windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `glob` module, which provides a platform-independent way of doing wildcard matching. For example, `glob('*.txt')` would return a list of all txt files in the current directory.

```
import fileinput
import sys
from glob import glob

for line in fileinput.input(glob(sys.argv[1]):
     print(fileinput.filename(), fileinput.filelineno(), line)
```

If you want to retain the behavior where you can specify multiple inputs (so that doing `python test_fileinput.py *.txt *.csv other.md` would be valid behavior), you can modify your code the the following:

```
import fileinput
import sys
from glob import glob

all_files = [f for files in sys.argv[1:] for f in glob(files)]

for line in fileinput.input(all_files):
     print(fileinput.filename(), fileinput.filelineno(), line)
```

Comment: glob is great I know it, but that's slightly different from what I'm asking.

Comment: So there is no way this can be done in Windows without using something  like `glob`, right? If you're sure about it, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @laike9m -- I'm fairly certain it's not possible using either the standard Windows command line or Powershell. I did a cursory search online, and it doesn't look like Windows natively supports wildcard expansion.