# passing wildcard arguments from bash into python

Tags: python, bash, scripting, arguments

I'm trying to practice with python script by writing a simple script that would take a large series of files named A_B and write them to the location B\A. The way I was passing the arguments into the file was

```
python script.py *
```

and my program looks like

```
from sys import argv
import os
import ntpath
import shutil

script, filename = argv

target = open(filename)

outfilename = target.name.split('_') 

outpath=outfilename[1]
outpath+="/"
outpath+=outfilename[0]

if not os.path.exists(outfilename[1]):
    os.makedirs(outfilename[1])

shutil.copyfile(target.name, outpath)

target.close()
```

The problem with this is that this script the way it's currently written is set up to only accept 1 file at a time. Originally I was hoping the wildcard would pass one file at a time to the script then execute the script each time.

My question covers both cases:

1. How could I instead pass the wildcard files one at a time to a script.

and

2. How do I modify this script to instead accept all the arguments? (I can handle list-ifying everything but argv is what I'm having problems with and im a bit unsure about how to create a list of files)

Comment: All `python script.py *` does is set `filename = '*'`. If you want that to be a wildcard, you need to handle that in your script.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's not true, the `*` is expanded by the shell and all matching files are passed to the script.

Comment: Tom is definitely on track since the error I receive is "too many values to unpack"

Comment: @TomFenech ah, I think that might be shell-dependent, it doesn't happen on the Windows command prompt

Comment: @Skyler so why not make `filenames = argv[1:]` then iterate over it? It won't matter if it contains none, one or many, and you never actually *use* `script`.

Comment: And it seems like '*' is passed in Windows, but my main question is to get this working for bash so unless someone has an elegant cross-platform solution they feel like posting getting things bash operational covers my bases.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for some reason my program wasn't compiling without script originally, once I switched to the array slicing method I stopped having problems but before that I received an error say "Type Error: coercing to Unicode" whenever I removed script

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501761/passing-multple-files-with-asterisk-to-python-shell-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, both of which involve a loop.

To pass the files one by one, use a shell loop:

```
for file in *; do python script.py "$file"; done
```

This will invoke your script once for every file matching the glob `*`.

To process multiple files in your script, use a loop there instead:

```
from sys import argv
for filename in argv[1:]:
    # rest of script
```

Then call your script from bash like `python script.py *` to pass all the files as arguments. `argv[1:]` is an array slice, which returns a list containing the elements from `argv` starting from position 1 to the end of the array.

I would suggest the latter approach as it means that you are only invoking one instance of your script.

Comment: could you also add a little bit more to explain what argv[1:] is exactly, this is the first time I've encountered that (still pretty new to python but have experience with other languages)

Comment: @Skyler sure, I added a sentence explaining the array slice